# How far up the call stack should I use await for an async function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, asynchronous, async-await

I'm using typescript/react and my understanding of async functions is kind of basic.

I have two API calls I have to make and I have functions to call them from my UI that are async. I absolutely need those calls to have completed to render the component correctly, but it feels like the entire component's functions have to be declared async in order for this to happen.

I fixed an issue earlier in `getOverview()` by adding the await, but now, my issue is that the `createPage()` function doesn't wait for the list returned from `getOverview()` to have items inside it in order to perform any actions on it, so it ends up erroring. Do I need to await this function as well?

The awaits keep creeping up the stack and I don't know whether it's correct.

```
class overview extends React.Component<any, any> {
  
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      overviewList: [],
    };
  }

  async callAPI1() {
    return await api1()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.status_code === 200) {
          // return result data
        } else {
          // error redirect
        }
      });
  }

  async callAPI2() {
    return await api2()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.status_code === 200) {
          // return result data
        } else {
          // error redirect
        }
      });
  }

  async getOverview() {
    const list = [];
    list.concat(await this.callAPI1());
    list.concat(await this.callAPI2());

    this.setState({overviewList: list});
    return list;
  }

  createPage() {
    const overview = this.getOverview();
    return overview[1];
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Header</h1>
        { this.createPage() }
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: It needs to go up as high as you need to deal with the value being asynchronous. Note I wouldn't recommend mixing async/await syntax with .then, at least in the same function.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you want to call the external API for every render that happens inside React. For this reason you normally don't call methods invoking API calls inside the `render` function. They are mostly used inside [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) and/or [`componentDidUpdate`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate).

Here is an example based on your code:

```
class overview extends React.Component<any, any> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      overviewList: [],
    };
  }

  async callAPI1() {
    return this.trowIfNot200(await api1());
  }

  async callAPI2() {
    return this.trowIfNot200(await api2());
  }

  throwIfNot200(result) {
    if (result.status_code === 200) {
      return result;
    } else {
      throw result;
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount() {
    try {
      const overviewList = await Promise.all([this.callAPI1(), this.callAPI2()]);
      this.setState({overviewList});
    } catch (error) {
      this.setState({error: "There was a problem loading external data."}));
    }
  }

  render() {
    if (this.state.error) {
      return <div>{this.state.error}</div>;
    } else {
      return (
        <div>
          <h1>Header</h1>
          { this.state.overviewList[1] }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }
}
```

Note that `this.state.overviewList[1]` will return `undefined` as long as the data is still loading. React will not render anything for values that are `undefined`, `null` or `false`.

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <div>a {undefined} b {null} c {false} d</div>,
  document.querySelector("#root")
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```